# PSIM simulation of buck chopper

Tags: simulation, buck

I'm having some trouble simulating a closed loop buck converter I designed.I am using PSIM for verifying the correctness of my circuit, but I can't figure out why the output is all wrong.[image: PSIM circuit]

[image: Output Voltage]

It is supposed to be a 12 V to 5 V buck chopper at switching frequency = 200 kHz.Output power = 50 W.When a friend simulated a similar circuit on ORCAD, he used an isolation component for the gate drive part of MOSFET, but there seems to be no such block on PSIM.

How can I correct this?
EDIT 1:
Yes I did connect my n-channel MOSFET wrong, but correcting it (or using p-channel MOSFET) didn't give me the right output voltage of 5 V)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOS1 is backwards, so right now the output voltage will just be the input minus the voltage drop from the body diode.  It is, however, the correct type (you should be using an N channel FET, not P).  Typically you need a high-side gate driver with a bootstrap capacitor to use one though.  I recommend operating the converter in open loop at 50% duty cycle.  You can then confirm if the switching action is working correctly and you should get 6V on the output.  If that works, then the problem lies in your compensator values.

Comment: Yes at first I simulated the open loop circuit, and it wasn't accurately 5V, it was lower than that.Why do you say the output will be 6V?

Comment: Well, for an ideal buck converter in CCM (continuous conduction mode), the output is D*Vin.  For 50% duty cycle, that works out to 0.5 * 12V = 6V.  Since you have a diode instead of a second mosfet, the converter can operate in DCM (discontinuous conduction mode) if the load current is too small.  In DCM, the formula doesn't work anymore.  However, I think the load current is high enough that that shouldn't be the case.  Can you provide a plot of the switch node voltage (mosfet source) and the inductor current?

Comment: Oh I see now. My output must be 5V, so I wasn't getting why you said 6V.Funnily enough,I simulated the same circuit on a friend's laptop on the same version of PSIM and the circuit now works fine after I changed the Mosfet connection.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an N-channel device as your pass transistor when you should be using a P-channel device in this type of circuit configuration. Look at the parasitic diode component across MOS1 - you can see that it will be conducting all the time.

Change it to a P-channel device like this: -

[image]

As for not finding an isolation component in PSIM, you should be able to use a VCVS. If you do this you will be able to use an N-channel MOSFET for MOS1 but with drain connected to the input supply.

Answer (score 0):

Your MOSFET MOS1 is in the circuit the wrong way round so it's just acting like a diode. If you flip it 180 degrees, it should work as expected.

Comment: Not really! It will act as a fairly inefficient source follower and not turn on properly.

Comment: @Andyaka In a practical circuit, if the gate voltage must be higher than the Vgs threshold with respect to the source then it will act correctly as a switch. For many simulation programs, a positive output typically turns on the switch.